# openwebrtc application is not accessible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, openwebrtc

I have downloaded the successfully build openwebrtc public image from docker hub and using it. After running the following command 'openwebrtc-daemon', I tried to access the application from the browser with the public_ip:10717 of the AWS EC2 instance. When I check the app to which ports it is listening to using the following command- 'netstat -pan', service openwebrtc-daemon is listening to the following ports 10717,10719 and the ip its listening to is 127.0.0.1. Not able to access the application. What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

After exposing localhost:10717 using localtunnel

```
 npm install -g localtunnel
 lt --port 10717
```

You will receive a url, for example https://gqgh.localtunnel.me

And inject the below script using tampermonkey for chrome

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://gqgh.localtunnel.me/owr.js"; // use you own http link for owr.js 
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

And the rest is as usual 
Refer  https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc/wiki/Running-and-Testing for detailed instructions about how to test your openwebrtc server.